# How to use cell value as worksheet name in another workbook using the vlookup function?

Tags: excel

I have two separate workbooks, one called **Form.xlsx** and one called **Database.xlsx**. While in **Form.xlsx** the user will select a value from a dropdown in cell C3. I would like for the value to then be used as the Worksheet name in the **Database.xlsx** workbook.

For Example:

The C3 drop down list will be:

- Florida
- Ohio
- Indiana

When a user selects say **Florida** from the dropdown, I would then like for that value to be plugged into a vlookup statement as the worksheet name like:

`=vlookup(C3,'C:\Users\Williasa\[Database.xlsx]Florida!$B$4:$F$6,5,FALSE)`

Is there any way that I can do that? If possible I would like to stay away from a INDIRECT statement since the Database.xlsx workbook will not be open when users are using the Form.xlsx.strong text

**EDIT**

I feel like I need to clarify something here.

On the Form is another drop-down criteria with 3 options in it in cell **B14**:

- Fax
- Email
- Phone

I would like the vlookup to first take me to the correct worksheet defined by cell **C3** (Florida, Ohio, or Indiana), search A7:A9 for the **B14** drop-down value that matches, then bring in the cell value of B7:B9 to the original cell where I am running this formula.

I apologize if I am using incorrect wording, trying my best to explain it!

Answer (score 0):

If the drop-down list is small and constant or changes rarely, you could do something like:

```
CHOOSE(X,'C:\Users\Williasa\[Database.xlsx]Florida'!$B$4:$F$6, 'C:\Users\Williasa\[Database.xlsx]Ohio'!$B$4:$F$6, 'C:\Users\Williasa\[Database.xlsx]Indiana'!$B$4:$F$6)
```

Where `X` is a formula equal to the index of the dropdown choice (so 1 for Florida).

Comment: Yes the drop-down list will not be changing. Would I place the Choose formula inside of the =vlookup? I added a little more clarification in what I am trying to accomplish above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you would place that `CHOOSE` expression inside of your `VLOOKUP`, e.g `=VLOOKUP(B14,CHOOSE(...),5,FALSE)`.